# How to Properly Unit Test onlyOwner

Tags: ether, hardhat, unittesting, chai

My contract inherits the `ownable.sol` which has a mint() method that is marked `onlyOwner` like below:

```js
 function mint(address _to, string memory newTokenURI) public onlyOwner
```

I know that within the `ownable` if the owner check fails it would return a rejected message `"Ownable: caller is not the owner"`. I am trying to test my mint function's user access  to do full test coverage. Note: I am using the chai-matchers library

```js
describe("EFTContract", function () {
  let token721;
  let TEST_URI1 = "ipfs://tokenurifor1";
  beforeEach(async function () {
    EFT721Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("EFTNFT");
    [owner, account1, ...otheraccounts] = await ethers.getSigners();
    token721 = await EFT721Contract .deploy();
  });

  
  describe("Ownership Tests", function () {
    // ok
    it("Testowner can call mint()", async function () {
      expect(await token721.mint(account1.address, TEST_URI1)).to.not.be.reverted;
    });
    // fails
    it("Test guest should not call mint()", async function () {
      // mint 1 so we have a valid token to try to query with tokenURI()
      await token721.mint(account1.address, TEST_URI1);
      // connect to guest account to try and mint
      await expect(token721
        .connect(account1.address)
        .mint(account1.address, TEST_URI1))
        .to.be.rejectedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    });'
  });
```

When I run this the first test passes but the second fails with the following error:

```
"VoidSigner cannot sign transactions (operation=\"signTransaction\", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=abstract-signer/5.6.2)"
```

I know I can replace that assert to pass the test replacing it with the code below but I believe that isnt properly testing ownership access of the ownable.sol contract:

```js
 await expect(token721
        .connect(account1.address)
        .mint(account1.address, TEST_URI1))
        .eventually.to.rejectedWith(Error, "VoidSigner cannot sign transactions (operation=\"signTransaction\", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=abstract-signer/5.6.2)");
```

How can I instead modify the second test case to properly compare against `"Ownable: caller is not the owner"?

**Solution:** It looks like I should wait for the promise to resolve before comparing the results. In this case it would provide an error instead of a rejected messaged so I should use `.to.be.revertedWith()` instead.

```js
    // mint
    it("Testowner can call mint()", async function () {
      expect(await token721.mint(account1.address, TEST_URI1)).to.not.be.reverted;
    });

    it("Test guest should not call mint()", async function () {
      await expect(token721
        .connect(account1)
        .mint(account1.address, TEST_URI1))
        .to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `await` keyword is at the wrong place. Replace this part:

```js
      await expect(token721
        .connect(account1.address)
        .mint(account1.address, TEST_URI1))
        .to.be.rejectedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner");
```

Like this:

```js
      expect(await token721
        .connect(account1.address)
        .mint(account1.address, TEST_URI1))
        .to.be.rejectedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner");
```

Make sure to execute the `expect()` after the `await`.

Update: It's also because you're connecting to the account the wrong way. Don't do this:

`.connect(account1.address)`

Do this:

`.connect(account1)`

Comment: I tried that and It fails with the same message `Error: voidSigner cannot sign transactions`.

Comment: Then that's because you're using `.connect(account1.address)` which is incorrect you don't want to access the address when connecting so this is the right way: `.connect(account1)`

Comment: That makes sense. So the message improved. But it errors prior to to comparing the string. Currently it returnes`Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Ownable: caller is not the owner'`. Do I need a try catch to capture the error and compare against? The chai-matchers library should handle this but I dont see anything about it in their documentation

Comment: After a little more searching error is caught with `.to.be.revertedWith` instead of `rekectedWith`. Finally the promise should resolve before the expect otherwise we cant compare capture the error to compare against. So in this case it would be `await` before  `expect`. Can you modify your answer so I can accept?

Comment: If you test with Foundry you're a lot less likely to make these mistakes @Potion , since the tests are written in Solidity.

Comment: @RyanSea I have heard great things about foundry. I'll have to check it out.  But I dont think I can completely avoid the responsibility of testing in JS once I begin to integrate the contracts with my dapp

Comment: sure just updated the answer feel free to mark it as valid

Comment: how to test for success?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if @Merunas G's answer was on a different version of Hardhat Ethers (*), but moving the await didn't work for me.  This should work (note the use of `reverted` as was discussed in @Merunas's answer's comments):

```
await expect(token721
        .connect(account1.address)
        .mint(account1.address, TEST_URI1))
        .to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner");
```

However, the Ownable abstract contract uses a Custom Error (https://hardhat.org/hardhat-chai-matchers/docs/overview#reverts) so the answer (at least today - *) is:

```
await expect(token721
        .connect(account1.address)
        .mint(account1.address, TEST_URI1))
        .to.be.revertedWithCustomError(token721, "OwnableUnauthorizedAccount");
```

- - ethers6 introduced a lot of breaking changes